# How to set the background for a range of values with Google Visualization API?

Tags: charts, google-visualization

Suppose you have a line chart with values from 1 to 100, and you want to show that values between 50 and 80 are "normal". How can you set the background of the chart between 50 to 80 to green using the Google Visualization API?

Here is an example using Dundas. $20 to $40 is pink: 
http://support2.dundas.com/OnlineDocumentation/WebChart2005/images/StripLinesAfter.png

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, there's no straightforward way to do this. Two ways I can think of off the top of my head:

- If you're happy with the functionality of the google image charts (as opposed to interactive visualization) the [fill options detailed here - look at solid/gradient/lined](http://code.google.com/apis/chart/image/docs/gallery/bar_charts.html#gcharts_solid_fills) may help.
- Use the [Combo Chart](http://code.google.com/apis/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/combochart.html) to add your upper and lower bounds as line series (where your actual data uses the bars themselves), to mimic the 'normal' area. It will involve adding two extra columns to your data table each time before drawing.

Comment: It looks like the fill options will work, but I am not calling the chart that way. I am using the javascript library http://code.google.com/apis/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/linechart.html . Is it possible to use fill options with the javascript library?

Comment: Does anyone know how I can archive this with the JS API as well?
I would like to use a gradient background to my linechart using the jsapi